# SWIFT access nested dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have a Dictionary that has a User object, and that User object is a dictionary that has a key "Name".
In Swift, i need to access the value for "Name".

So I did the following:

```
let user = question[kUserOwner] as! PFUser
let userName = user[kName] as! String
userButton.setTitle(userName, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
```

1) Is there really no easier/shorter way to do this?
In Objective C:

```
[_userButton setTitle:[[question objectForKey:kUserOwner] objectForKey:kName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I do realize that it is not Type safe but I can live with that, as long as I know what I am doing.

2) Is there any way i can avoid casting?

Comment: You mean like `question[kUserOwner][kName]`?

Comment: Yeah but that doesnt work, since it doesnt know what question[kUserOwner] is... have tried!

Comment: Note that your swift example isn't equivalent to your objc example.  The swift one will crash if `question` doesn't have a value for the `kUserOwner` key while the objc one won't.

Comment: @dan I know, But in this case, I know what question has a value, since it is assigned before showing the VC. I am trying to figure a way to force it to accept it, when i am 100% sure it is not nil :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you subscript, you get an Optional. And you cannot subscript an Optional. Therefore, while you can perhaps avoid *casting*, you cannot avoid *unwrapping*:

```
let dinner = ["name":"Matt"]
let douter = ["owner":dinner]
let name = douter["owner"]!["name"]
```

But that only works because Swift knows very specifically what `douter` is. It would be better, therefore, to do this in stages, as Swift expects you to do, e.g. with a nested series of `if let` bindings:

```
let dinner : AnyObject = ["name":"Matt"] as AnyObject
let douter : AnyObject = ["owner":dinner] as AnyObject
if let owner = douter["owner"] as? [NSObject:AnyObject],
    let name = dinner["name"] as? String {
        // do something with name
}
```

Comment: Here it is easy for Swift to infer the type. But in my case it is not, so it complains about the User dictionary being AnyObject which cannot be an argument to the title of the button (it expects a String)

Comment: I totally agree, and have modified my answer to say exactly that!

Comment: Just tried the following, and it worked, but still not very readable... damn swift, just plays hard to get:             userButton.setTitle((aQuestion[kUserOwner]![kName] as! String), forState:UIControlState.Normal)

Comment: What is the downside of force casting beside the risk of crash if the value is nil? I mean if I know that it is not nil, it is a risk I am willing to take. A ? might also return nil, in which case it will crash anyway unless I provide a default value instead right? something like:         questionLabel.text = (aQuestion[kQuestionText] as? String) ?? ""

Comment: Modified my answer to show the `if let` nest for my example; it's clear how to adapt that for your situation. I admit it seems like a pain in the butt, but that's how Swift works so you really just should suck it up.

Comment: Yeah, I can see what you you mean. I will go with the following and take my chances as long as I am sure that question is not nil: userButton.setTitle((aQuestion[kUserOwner]![kName] as! String), forState:UIControlState.Normal)

Comment: "What is the downside of force casting beside the risk of crash" None; that _is_ the risk.

Comment: But what is the point of it not crashing if the value is nil? I mean that logic should be present before using the actual dictionary/object.

Comment: Sorry you lost me. The point, in relation to your original question, is that you must do _something_ because this stuff is arriving from Objective-C and therefore lacks sufficient typing, whereas Swift has strict typing. It doesn't matter at what stage of things you supply a type, but you must supply one. As I think you said yourself, you can end up with an AnyObject but you can't assign that to a button title.

Comment: I am basically complaining that Swift has strict typing... ! I mean we are not stupid, so they should fix that! Anyway, thanks I have accepted your answer.

Comment: I don't actually agree. I have turned all my Objective-C code into Swift, and you know what? I _was_ stupid. There were _lots_ of places where I was just making dumb or lazy assumptions about what something was. My code is _much_ clearer and more reliable now.

Comment: Well, it probably is much safer :) Anyway, thanks. Just need to get better at it.